# call function only for one bootstrap modal from 3 modals in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm stuck a little bit in a page where I have 3 bootstrap modals and I want to apply a function only for one modal and for the other two not.

```
$("body").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    alert('modal Open');
    //this alert should happen only on Modal demo 2
    //I cannot add an id or class on modal because this is created dynamically 
    //so pls I do not need this suggestion

})
```

My function look like this: the selector on body looks for `shown.bs.modal` event and apply script my problem is that I want to apply this script only for particular modal and not for all modal from this page and other pages.

**[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5994/)**

Answer (score 1):

you have to:

Set different IDs for each Modal (you should use a ID in one Page only once!)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
```

and

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
```

than you can target only one of the modals:

```
$("#myModal1").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5995/

Comment: //I cannot add an id or class on modal because this is created dynamically

Comment: Than you have to change the dynamically generation of your html. How you generate the html? It's also not "right" html-code if you use a ID more than once.

Comment: I generate the modal through http://wb.agilecoders.de/demo/#.U3nBCijb5GE and I have a div where I put an wicket id and this id generate the modal.

Comment: Than you better asked someone know about Apache wicket how to generate right html-code.

I cant believe apache wicked cant generate right html-code.